# Are JavaScript events always executed even if there is no one listening?

Tags: javascript, events

Are events in JavaScript always fired even if there are no listeners attached?

Lets say "mousemove", I move the mouse but there are no listeners in the whole app, will the browser still construct a new Event and fire it, or will it optimize and consider the fact that if there are no event listeners, just ignore the data.

I assume that each browser works differently and I'm assuming they use patterns like *observer* and what not, but is there a spec around that states how it should be?

Comment: This is like the "tree falls in the forest" question, but banning the use of microphones...

Comment: Are you asking about browser events?

Comment: This could be handled quite differently on a browser-by-browser, engine-by-engine basis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Feel free to downvote this if you feel this is not correct but from my understanding and according to the [DOM Level 2 Events Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow) there is a sense that events are always constructed and executed but listeners need to be there, of course, to actually register them.

The reason I say "there is a sense that events are always constructed and executed" is because the Spec mentions that

> This method allows the registration of event listeners on the event
>   target. If an EventListener is added to an EventTarget while it is
>   processing an event, it will not be triggered by the current actions
>   **but may be triggered during a later stage of event flow, such as the
>   bubbling phase**. If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on
>   the same EventTarget with the same parameters the duplicate instances
>   are discarded. They do not cause the EventListener to be called twice
>   and since they are discarded they do not need to be removed with the
>   removeEventListener method.

So if event listeners are dynamically added, there needs to be a way for the the page to know to register and listen to them. How each browser handles this is probably different as @JAAulde mentioned above but I do not think browsers would optimize for the fact that an event listener exists or not or at least nothing drastic.

Comment: Thanks @aug! This is exactly what I was looking for. Even if browsers work differently, there is always a "it should be this way" clause that you just found.